# How to let the user enter any amount of variable from Console

Tags: c#

This is the code that I have made that rolls two dice until a pair appear.
My question is, is there a way for the user to enter any amount of dice he/she wants?

I don't want to create 50 int dice. If I use an array or List I would have the same problem. I'd have to assign each array section to numbergen 50 or more times. Maybe there is something I am missing?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Random numbergen = new Random();
            int dice1=0;
            int dice2=1;
            for (int counter = 0; counter <= 1; counter++)
            {
                while (dice1 != dice2)
                {
                    dice1 = numbergen.Next(1, 7);
                    dice2 = numbergen.Next(1, 7);
                    if (dice1 == dice2)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        Console.WriteLine(dice1 + "\t" + dice2);
                        counter++;
                        dice1 = 0;
                        dice2 = 1;


                    }
                    else if (dice1 != dice2)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        Console.WriteLine(dice1 + "\t" + dice2);
                    }
                    if (counter ==1 )
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Comment: From the title it sounds like you need a `List<int>` or `int[]` but I am not sure what you are actually looking for.

Comment: If there are seven or more dice then the answer is always that there is a pair among them.  You can't have seven numbers each between one and six, and have them all different.

Comment: uhm i am not sure how List<int> would help. If the user wants to roll a 20 dices, i would have to list everying from 0-20  @Habib

Comment: Is your question how to take an integer input from the user, or how to represent an arbitrary number of integers? It seems like you are asking one question in the title and an entirely different question in the question.

Comment: how to take user input. That input will have to correspond to the dice number somehow. For example, if the user enter 5, the output will show 5 columns of randomly generated number(dice 1-6). @Eric Lippert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version where all die must match.

```
using System;

namespace Dicey
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numberOfDice;

            // check for and retrieve the number of dice the user wants.
            if (args.Length != 1 || !int.TryParse(args[0], out numberOfDice))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please provide the number of dice.");
                return; // exit because arg not provided
            }

            // Must have at least one and set some arbitrary upper limit
            if (numberOfDice < 1 || numberOfDice > 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please provide a number of dice between 1 and 50");
                return; // exist because not in valid range
            }

            var dice = new int[numberOfDice]; // create array of die (ints)
            var rand = new Random();
            var match = false; // start with false (match not found yet)

            while (!match) // loop until match becomes true
            {
                var message = string.Empty;
                match = true; // assume match until something doesn't match

                for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDice; i++)
                {
                    // initialize dice at index i with the random number
                    dice[i] = rand.Next(1, 7);

                    // build the message line to write to the console
                    message += dice[i]; // first add the die's number

                    if (i < numberOfDice - 1)
                        message += "\t"; // if not at the end, add a tab

                    // check if the previous die (except for the first of course) has a different number
                    if (i > 0 && dice[i - 1] != dice[i]) 
                        match = false; // uh oh, not all match. we have to keep going
                }

                // print out the message
                Console.ForegroundColor = match ? ConsoleColor.Yellow : ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To me this code seems complex,but ill try my best to understand it. In this situation many other people suggested that i use an array or some sort, to me that seems like a dead end, I tried several times to do what they said but no avail. Do you think using list and arrays can solve this problem like they said or did they not understand my question because i phrase it so poorly? @ James R.

Comment: @aimepie I hope I implemented it the way you were wanting in that all die have to match. Yes, an array or list is the best thing to use for something like this, when you have a variable number of items to deal with. It's really not that complicated if you break it down into its components. Good luck!

Comment: @aimepie, I added some comments to hopefully help you understand my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a number of integers specified by the user, then the easiest way to do that would be using an array like `int x[z]` where z is the number specified by the user, or, even better, make a list of ints in the form `List<int>` where you can add ints depending on the number the user entered.

You wouldn't have the same problem as if you had many different variables when doing numbergen, because you could just have a for loop go through your list or array, giving them a value assigned by numbergen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
Ask user to enter a number of dice store it in a variable then create an array of that size.